файл apk не запускается на телефоне после успешной компиляции через buildozer
в общем у меня есть гигантский проект на kivy где есть такие библиотеки как matplotlib,requests,os,googletrans,random, (так же разумеется фреймворк kivy), апк на нем прекрасно собирается, но не запускается на телефоне, что делать?
buildozer.spec - https://pastebin.com/GmT7wmsE
делал на colab двумя командами
!rm -rf sample_data/ && pip install buildozer && sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-17-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev && pip3 install --upgrade Cython==0.29.33 virtualenv && pip install kivymd && sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip build-essential git python3 python3-dev ffmpeg libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev libgstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good libffi7 build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi7 libffi-dev && yes | buildozer init && printf "~~~~~~~~instruction~~~~~~~~\nAfter initialization, load the file with the program and name it <>.\nIn the buildozer.spec file, change the name of your program.\nIf you are using the socket library, uncomment the <> line.\nChange <> to <>.\nDownload the .apk file after finishing the second step ~ compilation." > README.txt && echo -e "\033[1m\e[1;35mInitialization completed! \e[0m"

!yes | buildozer -v android debug && yes | buildozer android clean && echo -e "\033[1m\e[1;35mCompilation completed, you can download the .apk file! \e[0m"

(p.s. если что файлы icon presplash и прочие txt находятся в проекте)

в общем полазил я в android studio и нашел ошибку оказывается там в googletrans прога не видит модуль httpcore
